# Deriving ordered statistics minimum cdf

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, order-statistics

Assume ${{X}_{1}}$, ${{X}_{2}}$, ${{X}_{3}}$,...,${{X}_{n}}$  are i.i.d. samples from distribution with density f, and cdf F.

Let V=min( ${{X}_{1}}$, ${{X}_{2}}$, ${{X}_{3}}$,...,${{X}_{n}}$)

To find the minimum $${B}_{v}={\{V\ge{v}\}}=\{{X}_{1}\ge{v}\}\cap\{{X}_{2}\ge{v}\}\cap...\cap\{{X}_{n}\ge{v}\}$$

So, $$P(V\ge{v})=[1-F(v)]^{n}$$

The cdf is
 $$F_{v}(V)=1-[1-F(v)]^{n}$$

The density is $${f}_{v}(V)=\frac{d}{dv}[1-F(v)]^{n}=nf(v)[1-F(v)]^{n-1}$$

To find the density, why did we use $[1-F(v)]^{n}$ instead of $1-[1-F(v)]^{n}$, shouldn't we used the cdf to derive the pdf?

Comment: I just verified the calculus, it should be using the cdf $1-[1-F(v)]^{v}$.  So, the $\frac{d}{dv}$ part is misleading.

Comment: @jbowman, we posted simultaneously.  I calculated both several times, they didn't come out the same to me, could I have forgotten my calculus?

Comment: The density is indeed the derivative of $\Pr(V\le v)$: in your last line you lost a negative sign and mistakenly got the correct result.  (Just draw a graph. $F(v)$ is increasing, whence $1-F(v)$ decreases and therefore so does $(1-F(v))^n$: thus, its derivative *must* be negative and cannot be a density.)  This is starting to sound like a question about using the Chain Rule rather than about probability or statistics...

Comment: @whuber, $F_{v}(V)$ is the cdf, not $Pr(V\ge{v})$.  So, You get density by taking derivative of $F_{v}(V)$.

I have the following 
$$\Big((1-F(v))^n\Big)'=(1-F(v))'n(1-F(v))^{n-1}=-f(v)n(1-F(v))^{n-1}$$
And
$$\Big(1-(1-F(v))^n\Big)'=0-(-f(v)n(1-F(v))^{n-1})=f(v)n(1-F(v))^{n-1}$$
This is why I said they are not the same.

Comment: -1 The OP has also asked how to find the derivatives of $(1-F(v))^n$ and $1 - (1-F(v))^n$ on math.SE and accepted an answer there. This is not a question about the Chain Rule (as whuber suggests) but more basic: does $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[1-G(x)]$ equal $-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}G(x)$ or not? Yes, if one computes the derivatives correctly, but the OP makes a sign error in computing one of them, concludes that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[1-G(x)]=+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}G(x)$ and refuses to try to understand the answers and comments here on stats.SE that point out his mistake.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I don't understand what you are trying to answer. Clearly, those two are different answers(see two posts above this one), only one of them is right.  You get the right answer by taking derivative of $Pr({V}\ge{v})$, why is that?  You are suppose take derivative of the cdf, but that doesn't give you the right answer.

Comment: Also, is my first comment correct in saying $\frac{d}{dv}$ part is misleading?

Comment: **YOU** write $${f}_{v}(V)=\frac{d}{dv}[1-F(v)]^{n}=nf(v)[1-F(v)]^{n-1}$$ which is **WRONG** two ways. **FIRST**, the density is the derivative of the CDF which happens to be $1-[1-F(v)]^{n}$ **as you had written on the previous line**, not $[1-F(v)]^{n}$.  **SECOND**, you made a **SIGN ERROR** in computing $\frac{d}{dv}[1-F(v)]^{n}$ and found $-\frac{d}{dv}[1-F(v)]^{n}$ instead, **which happens to be the density** because $$\frac{d}{dv}F_V(v)=\frac{d}{dv}[1-(1-F(v))^n]=-\frac{d}{dv}(1-F(v))^n$$ **as has been pointed out to you repeatedly**. **Your** mistake, which you refuse to accept.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, thanks, that's a great answer!  Finally clear to me!  

I wrote that in the first comment, but nobody confirmed, so I thought I was wrong.  I was trying to understand the 4th page, http://www.markirwin.net/stat110/Lecture/Section37.pdf so, I guess he wrote it wrong.  Again, thanks for your help, I appreciate it, it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of seeing how the density arises.  First, from the definition of the density as the derivative of the distribution, we have that
$$
f_v(v)=\frac{dF_v(v)}{dv}=-n[1-F(v)]^{n-1}\frac{d(1-F(v))}{dv}=nf(v)[1-F(v)]^{n-1}
$$
(a simple application of the chain rule.)

Second (and less rigorously) is to note that $f_v(v)$ is the limit of probability that the minimum occurs between $v$ and $v+\Delta v$ divided by $\Delta v$ as $\Delta v$ goes to $0$. Now there are $n$ choices for which statistic is the minimum, that statistic has probability $f(v)\Delta v$ of occurring between $v$ and $v+\Delta v$, and the other $n-1$ statistics have probability $[1-F(v)]^{n-1}$ of all being greater than $n$.  Multiplying all these terms and dividing by $\Delta(v)$ gives us
$$
f_v(v) =  nf(v)[1-F(v)]^{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

> To find the density, why did we use $[1-F(v)]^{n}$ instead of $1-[1-F(v)]^{n}$, shouldn't we used the cdf to derive the pdf?

The cumulative distribution function can be seen as the integral of the density

$$F(v) = \int_{-\infty}^{v} f(x) dx$$

The complementary cumulative distribution function can also be seen as the integral of the density but with other bounds

$$\bar{F}(v) = 1 - F(v) = \int_{v}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$

---

If we diffentiate these two we get according to the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) the following

$$\begin{array}{rcccr}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} F(v) &=&\frac{\partial}{\partial v}  \int_{-\infty}^{v} f(x) dx &=& f(v)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\bar{ F}(v) &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial v}  \int_{v}^{\infty} f(x) dx &=& - f(v)\\
\end{array}$$

So you can just as well use $F(v)$ as $\bar{F}(v) = 1 - F(v) $ to derive $f(v)$ by differentiation. The only difference is in the minus sign.

---

Regarding that minus sign. There is a little mistake in your equation. It should be:

$${f}_{v}(V)= \color{red}{-}\frac{d}{dv}[1-F(v)]^{n}=nf(v)[1-F(v)]^{n-1}$$