# Find pdf for minimum of 4 random variables

Tags: probability, self-study, order-statistics

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$,and $X_4$ be four mutually independent random
>   variables, each with p.d.f. $$f(x) = 3(1-x)^2\quad
>   \mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(x)$$If $Y$ is the minimum of these four variables,
>   find the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of $Y$.

So far I have:
\begin{align}
P(Y \le y) &= P(\min(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) \le y)  \\[5pt]
    &=1- P(y\le X_1, y\le X_2, y\le X_3, y\le X_4)  \\[5pt]
    &=1-P(y\le X_1)P(y\le X_2)P(y\le X_3)P(y\le X_4) \tag{independence}  \\[5pt]
    &=1-\bigg(\int^1_y f(x_1)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int^1_y f(x_2)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int^1_y f(x_2)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int^1_y f(x_2)dx\bigg)
\end{align}
And then I get stuck. I'm not even totally sure that is correct.

If anyone just has a written explanation, that would really help as I'm not entirely sure exactly what my goal is with this problem.

Comment: This seems to be for homework or some other form of self study? That's OK, but then please add the `self-study` tag. See [this help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for why. Do you know how to perform the integral of f(x)dx?

Comment: I wonder why you think that whenever the _minimum_ of four numbers is smaller than $y$, it is _absolutely not the case_ that all four numbers are smaller than $y$. That is what your second quality is claiming.  Now to how to fix your answer. If the **minimum** is _larger_ than $y$, then **all four** numbers must be larger than $y$, right? So, $$P(\min\{X_i\} )> y) = P(\text{all four}~X_i > y) =P(X_1>y)\cdots P(X_4>y)$$

Comment: @Mjt It seems you have accidentally created a second account! [See this page to help you merge your accounts back together](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This is important because it will allow you to edit your own questions without waiting for other people to approve your edits.

Comment: This situation seems adequately covered in the question and answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23005/deriving-ordered-statistics-minimum-cdf. You can find *many* similar questions asked and answered by searching our site for keywords like [distribution minimum independent](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distribution+minimum+independent).